# Can't update to WhatsApp latest version

Tags: google-play-store, updates, whatsapp-messenger

I got a message saying "This version of WhatsApp became obsolete on **December 24, 2015**. Please go to the Play Store to download the latest version" and that I must update the app from the Google Play Store.

However, when I try to update, it hangs at the message saying *Updating* and never finishes downloading the update. I have been trying for days, until now, and nothing. I am now stuck without access to WhatsApp.

Please can you advise?

Comment: Go to the app manager, and clear the cache of Play Store and WhatsApp

Comment: Thanks Bro21, I have tried that and still doesnt work. Playstore just shows that its busy installing but it never completes the installation. I have to just stop it.

Comment: You can go with @VivekJi 's solution, to download the **.apk** from the official link. Make sure to allow download from untrusted sources. once it finishes, click on notification and open with package manager

Answer (score 5):

Don't worry. Try to download whatsapp apk directly from whatsapp official site. For that here is [link](https://www.whatsapp.com/android/).